# Elements of Galois group preserve the multiplicity of roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I just learned about Galois group and had trouble reasoning about the following :

> Suppose $E$ is the splitting field for $f$, which is a degree $n$ irreducible polynomial over a field $F$. Consider two distinct roots of $f$ with different multiplicity. Can there exist an element of the Galois group $Gal(E/F)$ that sends one to the other?

I am guessing that such an element doesn't, so informally I tried to argue that if such an element exists, then $\sigma(f) \neq f$. While intuitively I think that $\sigma(f) \neq f$ might cause a problem to $\sigma$ being a field automorphism, I cannot find a reasonable way to argue about it and whether my guess is correct in the first place.

Comment: Just because $E$ is the splitting field over $f$ does not mean that it is a Galois extension of $F$. Does the question give any indication of a Galois closure or perhaps that $E$ is in fact the Galois extension?

Comment: I think the question intentionally left that as unspecified.

Comment: What do you mean "with different degrees"? Since $f$ is irreducible, then every root $\alpha$ of $f$ has degree $n$, if by degree you mean $[F(\alpha) : F]$.

Comment: @RichardD.James  Sorry I should replace "degree of the root" with "multiplicity of root".

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but if $f$ has a root, $\alpha$, with multiplicity lets say $k$ then $(x-\alpha)^k$ divides $f(x)$ which should contradict irreducibility.

Comment: @bowlofpetunias But it might be the case that $a\notin F$.

Comment: @bowlofpetunias For an explicit example, take $F = \mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and $f = x^p - t$. Then $f$ is irreducible over $F$, but factors as $(x - \sqrt[p]{t})^p$ over $\mathbb{F}_p(\sqrt[p]{t})$. So $\sqrt[p]{t}$ is a root of $f$ of multiplicity $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $a,b$ are $F$-conjugates then the multiplicity of $a$ and $b$ are the same in every polynomial of $F[x]$.

Let $\sigma$ be the natural isomorphism $F(a)\to F(b)$ and $f(x)\in F[x]$, then $$f(x) = (x-a)^e g(x)\qquad with\qquad g(x)\in F(a)[x],g(a)\ne 0$$ where $e$ is the multiplicity of $a$ so that (applying $\sigma$ to the coefficients of those polynomials) $$f(x)=f^\sigma(x) = (x-b)^e g^\sigma(x), \qquad  g^\sigma(b)=g^\sigma(\sigma(a))=\sigma(g(a))\ne 0$$